# Open android tablet in fastboot mode for Lenovo A1000-T

Tags: android, adb, bootloader, tabletools, fastboot

How did you go into fastboot mode? I am not able to figure out.

```
adb reboot bootloader
adb reboot-bootloader
adb reboot fastboot
```

None of them worked, However

```
adb reboot recovery opens it in recovery mode.
```

Niether of them worked. I have installed Lenovo Le Tools also.

Also tried to open it by pressing  -

```
Vol down + Power (opens factory mode)
Vol up + Power (opens recovery mode)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Backspace + power seems to do the trick :)

> Unplug your USB line, then shut down Lenovo IdeaTab A1000, next press the backspace key. Go on pressing the power key to enter bootloader. Then connect Lenovo IdeaTab A1000 with PC, and fastbootusb will come out in Lenovo IdeaTab A1000. Pay more attention that never press mount at this time.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20160624144157/http://www.yumapk.com/How-to-get-root-access-on-Lenovo-IdeaTab-A1000.html

Comment: Backspace? 
Do You mean to say volume down?